# How do I populate one attributes table column based on a value from another column? Qgis

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am trying to populate all data points with an elevation based on the fid. Basically, all fid's of 0 have an elevation of 1700, all fid's of 1 have an elevation of 1740 (there are 48 fid's) ... There are over 5000 data points to populate so doing it manually is not an option. Is there a way to building an expression in orfer to populate the elevation column automatically?

[image]

Comment: You should build an expression using the [Field Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html).

Comment: If there are 48 elevations to match with fid's and no mathematical relationship between them, the simplest way would be to create a table with no geometry with two columns fid and elevation and to join it to your layer via the layer's properties.

Comment: Maybe an expression such as `elev = 1700+[fid]*40` would work?

Answer (score 2):

Use the field calculator and insert an "if" statement or a "case" statement to populate the values in your "elevation" field.

```
CASE 
  WHEN "FID" = 0 THEN 1700
  WHEN "FID" = 1 THEN 1740
END
CASE
WHEN "FID" > 1 THEN "CNG_(Meters)"
END
```